# C++ Memory Scanning

Tags: c++, memory

I have a application that I need to scan for certain datatypes in the memory.  To get some benchmarking tests, I whipped up this program :

```
long count = 0;

MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION meminfo;
unsigned char *addr = 0;

HANDLE hProc = GetCurrentProcess();

while (true){

    if ( VirtualQueryEx( hProc, addr, &meminfo, sizeof( meminfo ) ) == 0 ){

        break;

    }

    if ( ( meminfo.State & MEM_COMMIT ) && ( meminfo.Protect & WRITABLE ) ){

        addr = (unsigned char*)meminfo.BaseAddress + meminfo.RegionSize;

        count++;

        printf("%d",count);

    }

}

printf("%ld\n",count);
```

This program doesn't work, it blocks/crashes at the first memory chunk.  And conceptually it fails too, ideally I need pointers to all of the variables in the current process, so I can check if they're of any relevance to me.  I've google'd around for a while now to no avail, if someone could push me in the right direction that'd be great.

I know it's generally a bad idea to do this in the first place, I'd just like to know how it'd be done if I needed to do it.

Comment: Probably just using a **debugger** might be the right way to a) spot the error in your program b) perform any type of process memory inspection you wish to achieve with your program. If on the other hand you're only concerned with some type of benchmarking there are tools like `gprof` specialized at this.

Comment: What do you mean, exactly, when you say that it crashes at the first memory chunk? Do you mean that there's an error when calling VirtualQueryEx? If so, what's the error code? (You can get this by calling [GetLastError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

Answer (score 1):

`WRITEABLE` (at the second `if` block) is not one of the memory protection constants. Did you mean `PAGE_READWRITE`? You can find the full list of options [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366786%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Memory access permissions are tricky. The rest of the function works though. This works, though one can view addr only when stepping through:

```
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    long count = 0;
    MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION meminfo;
    unsigned char *addr = 0;
    HANDLE hProc = GetCurrentProcess();
    while (true)
    {
        if (VirtualQueryEx(hProc, addr, &meminfo, sizeof(meminfo)) == 0)
        {
            // TODO GetLastError
            break;
        }

        // if ((meminfo.State & MEM_COMMIT) && (meminfo.Protect & PAGE_READWRITE))
        {
            addr = (unsigned char*) meminfo.BaseAddress + meminfo.RegionSize;
            count++;
            printf("%d", count);
        }
    }

    printf("%ld\n", count);
}
```